# Firebase: message:didRefreshRegistrationToken: Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-ios

I am seeing the message above when I include the following delegate method in my `AppDelegate+Firebase.m` module.

```
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
  ...
}
```

If I don't include the delegate method the app will crash when it receives a token refresh with:-

```
[FIRA_AppDelegate-1509991141874 messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000003c740'
```

I am setting the delegate earlier on in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
```

My question is, why am I seeing the warning?

I presume "it's primary class" is `AppDelegate` which is derived from `CDVAppDelegate` and only defines `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
  self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

So why is it telling me it will be implemented by the primary class?

*EDIT*

The RAW warning output

```
.../redsky-firebase/AppDelegate+Firebase.m:156:1: warning: category is
      implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class [-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation]
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
^
In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from .../redsky-firebase/Firebase/Firebase.h:37:
.../redsky-firebase/FirebaseMessaging.framework/Headers/FIRMessaging.h:252:1: note: method
      'messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:' declared here
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging
```

Code from `AppDelegate+Firebase.m:156`

```
// [START refresh_token]
/* If I don't include this, I get an exception saying unrecognised selector - out of date fcm libs? */
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FIREBASE: (AppDelegate+Firebase) messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken: %@", fcmToken);
    [Firebase.firebase sendToken:fcmToken];
}
```

Code from `FIRMessaging.h:252`

```
@protocol FIRMessagingDelegate 

/// This method will be called whenever FCM receives a new, default FCM token for your
/// Firebase project's Sender ID.
/// You can send this token to your application server to send notifications to this device.
- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging
    didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken
    FIR_SWIFT_NAME(messaging(_:didRefreshRegistrationToken:));
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it later? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope, still an issue.  I just ignore it now.